# Processing specific AWS SQS messages in specific threads

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

The Java application posts async jobs to AWS and gets back a JobID. When the async job is finished, a message will appear in an SQS queue with that JobID. *Each JobID is handled by a different thread.* Each of those threads also polls SQS for messages until it finds the message which contains its JobID. Additionally, the application is distributed into multiple services so there can't be a single SQS processor.

I saw that SQS returns a maximum of 10 messages and after they are returned, a visibility timeout is applied so that they are not re-sent to other consumers. However, my consumers are the threads that want to consume *only a single message* and let the rest be consumed by other threads. Should I set the visibility timeout to 0? Will this make it so all consumers get the same set of 10 messages on every request? What's the best way for each consumer to sift through all the messages and find the one it wants?

TL;DR: SQS has 100 messages and there are 100 consumers, one for each message. How should I go about having each consumer find the message it wants (based on a JobID).

EDIT: I know that this is **not** an appropriate usage of SQS and I'd be very glad to not use it at all but our main integration is with Amazon Textract for which it is mandatory to use SQS for its asynchronous operations. Each Textract request is processed by a different thread which means that they each need to get back a specific SQS message, consumers are not universal. Not to mention the possibility of a clustered environment for which I'd like to avoid having to do any synchronization...

EDIT 2: This is for an on-premises, Setup.exe based, dev-hands-off application where we want to minimize the amount of unneeded AWS services used (both for cost and for customer setup/maintenance reasons) as well as the use of external components, again to minimize customer deployment/maintenance/servers. I understand that we are living in the world of microservices but there are still applications that want to benefit from intelligent services without being cloud-native themselves.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an appropriate architecture for using Amazon SQS. Your processes should *not* be trying to find a specific message from an Amazon SQS queue.

You should find a different architecture for this message-passing task. Some ideas:

- Create a message in Amazon S3 with an 'expected' Key. Have the each thread look for that object as a return message. (This is effectively using Amazon S3 as a Key-Value Store.)
- Have a single Lambda function retrieve messages from SQS and update a database (or S3 as above). Then, have the threads consult the database instead of SQS.

Comment: Well I'd be **glad** to never have to use SQS but the architecture for Amazon Textract for asynchronous operations **mandates** SQS usage! Don't understand why considering other similar providers have **much simpler** implementations...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put something in between SQS and your threads. Like a DynamoDB table. You could have a Lambda function that processes **all** the SQS messages and just translates them into DynamoDB records. Then your different threads could easily check for the specific records they are interested in using a DynamoDB query.

Just because Textract mandates that you use SQS doesn't mean the final step in your architecture has to read those messages directly from SQS. In this case SQS is just a message bus that can integrate with other services in AWS, and those services are your building blocks you can use to create the architecture you need.

Comment: Well both of your comments make me think that these services (and I'm afraid most such services) are built with a specific majority of applications in mind, usually cloud-native and *vendor managed* services. Our application is an on-prem hands-off OG offering that needs to minimize *extra stuff* and this whole architecture requirement just to use Textract is already a huge hassle...

Comment: Minimizing "extra stuff" in AWS is the wrong way to use AWS. Services like SQS, S3, SNS, etc. are lower level building blocks, that you are intended to piece together to create a full solution. And yes, AWS itself is nothing but cloud-native and vendor managed services. I'm not sure what your complaint about that is. AWS is literally a cloud of vendor managed services, so what else did you expect?

Comment: I'd like to be able to **just** use Textract's intelligent processing in my minimal desktop application for some quick OCR without me or my customer having to go through the hassle of setting up 4 different services and accounts and permissions. Like I can do with Azure Form Recognizer for example.

Comment: It doesn't sound like what you want is possible. If you want to provide Amazon feedback on that I suggest contacting your AWS account rep, there's nothing random strangers on the Internet can do to fix that here. As for having to setup 4 different services you should be using some form of infrastructure-as-code to provision these services, and in that case it wouldn't matter how many services you are using, it would be a single step to set them all up.

Comment: It does indeed look like use cases like ours are just not considered anymore by service vendors. Infrastructure as code might seem like a solution until you need to support large customers (banks) that handle everything themselves and start inquiring as to why you need DynamoDB which is not mandatory for Textract and costs them money.